# Is it true that if $f\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $f\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1\leq p <\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is it true that if $f\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $f\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1\leq p <\infty$?

Well, I know that $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\overline{C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{{\lVert\cdot\rVert}_{W^{1,p}}}$, $1\leq p< \infty$.

I was trying to use the following properties of mollification:

If $f\in C(U)$, then 
$$
f^\varepsilon=\eta_\varepsilon* f\rightrightarrows f
$$
uniformly on compact subsets of $U$,

and $f^\varepsilon\in C^\infty(U_\varepsilon)$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, where $U_\varepsilon=\{x\in U:\text{dist}(x,\partial U)>\varepsilon\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true and it follows directly from the fact that any $C^1$ function is also weakly differentiable and its weak derivatives are its classical derivatives (which follows straight from the definition of the weak derivative). Since in your case $f$ and its derivatives have compact support, they are also in $L^p$.

Comment: I'm trying to see why $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Since $f$ is continuous and $supp f$ is compact then $f(supp f)$ is compact and consequently there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in supp f$. So $(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|^pdx)^{1/p}=(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus supp f} |f|^p+\int_{supp f} |f|^pdx)^{1/p}\leq (\int_{supp f} M^pdx)^{1/p}=M^p\mathcal{L}^n(supp f)^{1/p}<\infty$ since $\mathcal{L}^n$ is a Radon measure and $supp f$ is compact.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct argument.